# jQueryui Selectmenu - save value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectmenu

:)
I dont get how I can save the selected selectmenu-option into a variable?
Here is my Selectmenu:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#map").selectmenu();
    });
</script>
<form action="#">
    <fieldset>
        <select name="map" id="map">
            <option value="London">London</option>
            <option value="Berlin">Berlin</option>
            <option value="Nevada">Nevada</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I know that I need an Event. This Event would be `select` I guess. The jQueryui API Documentation (http://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#event-select) gives the following Code example:

```
$( ".selector" ).selectmenu({
  select: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```

But ... what is the `.selector` in my case? `#map`?

So it would be

```
$( "#map" ).selectmenu({
  select: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```

I guess? But where to insert my "action"? The `var map = X;`? And how does my code know which of the maps is selected?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the configuration object that you pass to [`selectmenu()`](https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/), there is a `select` property (a.k.a. `key`). Its `value` is an anonymous function (a callback). When you click one of the options, the corresponding event raises invoking that function.

You can get the select option with `$(this).val();`.

`$(this)` is a jQuery object. In the context of the callback, it is the element which invokes the function. In JavaScript, the `this` keyword is a very important and complex topic. You can read about it in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) and here in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/5247200). Basically, in your case, `$(this)` is the `option` element that was selected, triggering the `click` event.

[`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) is a method of the jQuery object that returns the current value of that object.

Once you have the `value`, just assign it to your `map` variable.

```js
var map = "";

$("#map").selectmenu({
  select: function(event, ui) {
    map = $(this).val();
    console.log(map);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<form action="#">
  <fieldset>
    <select name="map" id="map">
      <option value="London">London</option>
      <option value="Berlin">Berlin</option>
      <option value="Nevada">Nevada</option>
    </select>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Looks so easy... I would never figure that out on my own .. lol oO. Thank you so much! So "this" is the "value" of the selectmenu I guess. Thank you!

Comment: Accepted the answer :). I am so thankful! Web development seems like a jungle to me :D

Comment: To all of us when we start. Take your time reading the documentation of the new things that you experiment with. It will pay back. I edited the question with some links to the corresponding docs. (and to use a more accurate technical wording)